# How to select and play a song in Android

Tags: java, android, android-music-player

I have been wondering how I could select a song from my music library and play it by pressing a button. I have been searching for about and hour now and I cannot find an example that is not complete overkill. If you could point me in the right direction or give me some code would be great.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: This is the right direction: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html